# design pattern for using JSP and Javascript together on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jsp, design-patterns, web

I'm currently implementing a website using HTML/CSS, JSP/Servlet, and Javascript.
JSP controls which part of the page should be generated depending on a session value (for example, depending on whether a user is currently logged in or not), and Javascript has some actions on the elements of the generated document (e.g., div sections).

But I'm having an issue of using document div id values from Javascript when the div section is not generated because of the condition in the JSP code.

For example a page has two sections, where only one of the sections will be generated from JSP depending on the session value condition. And there is a Javascript file that has a set of functions to apply to each section using the 'id' of the div tag or its sub-tags. But since JSP does not generate all the sections, some of the 'id' used by the Javascript does not exist in the returned HTTP request. Below code snippets show an example.
JSP file is as below.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
...
<%
  if(some condition) {
%>
    <div id="someID"></div>
```

And as below, script.js has some function applied to the 'someID' to emit some html and apply actions on it. But someID would not exist if the JSP condition is not satisfied, producing a Javascript error for using unidentified id.

```
$function() {
  $('#someID').html( ..... )
}
```

The question is rather verbose, but simply stated,
"I'd like to conditionally generate some section of HTML from JSP, and apply some actions on the generated sections using Javascript. But the id of div section that is not generated from JSP because of the condition is used by the Javascript, which generates an error. How could I design this?"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if element exists via javascript to avoid errors:

```
if($('#someID').length > 0)) {
    $('#someID').html( ..... )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm currently using the check as you have shown in my code, but was wondering if designing a website this way is a good practice. I don't have much experience with web designs, so I'd like to know what people usually do to handle this kind of situation.

Comment: No, it isn't best practice. Embed any java code to jsp page isn't good practice. You can create multiple views for multiple states and choose appropriate view in controller instead. As for checking element existence via js - there is nothing wrong in that approach.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be a bit more concrete about your suggestion? I understand that jsp would better not to include the java code. Then who creates the multiple views and what do you mean by a view? Do you mean that JSP has all the multiple views in a single page and javascript selects which one to show to the user? It would be helpful for me what (javascript, jsp, servlet, etc) is responsible for what (view, controller, etc).

Comment: Typically controller returns entity called "view". It can be jsp or it can be name of tiles definition or name of velocity template or name of view of other templating engine. If you use plain jsp you can create two pages: show-logged.jsp and show-unlogged.jsp. After that in your controller you make decision what jsp show to user. if(condition) { show "show-logged" } else { show "show-unlogged" } (pseudocode)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check

```
if($('#someID')) {
  .. do this..
}
```

or

```
if(document.getElementById('someId')){
 ..do this...
}
```